# Calculating absolute value in Python

Tags: python, absolute-value

How do I make a program that asks for one floating point number in Python and then calculates the absolute value?  I've already tried the asking, but I can't make the line where it calculates the absolute value.

Comment: `absolute_value = abs(not_absolute_value)`?

Answer (score 25):

You can do it with the built-in [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) function:

```
absolute_val = abs(x)
```

Otherwise, without the built-in function, use math:

```
absolute_val = (x ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Comment: `x if x >= 0 else -x`. Using squaring and square root on a floating point number is probably both slower and more likely to give an inaccurate answer because of precision.

Comment: I've doing some quick tests, and I haven't actually found a value where `(x**2)**5 != abs(x)`, so I guess that's usable, but using floating point operations where a simple if/else can solve your problem seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @zstewart What about the `abs()` function? That one's probably reliable. The other one I just added as a "fun fact" I guess.

Comment: What do you mean what about `abs`? Of course `abs` is reliable, its a builtin, that's what it does. The tests I did were something like this: `all(((x**2)**0.5) == abs(x) for x in np.arange(-1954799126841, -1954799126851, -0.0001))`